# Silverlight on iPhone, iPad, and other mobile devices

Tags: silverlight, html, xaml, mobile, streaming

I have a client that wants to have their Silverlight media player work on mobile devices. I know Netflix uses Silverlight and it works on mobile devices. My question is how? I can find articles about Microsoft using html 5 to stream the media but I cant find any examples or documentation on how. Anyone have any places or examples to look? Are there external libraries I need to implement? Once again I have tried searching on Google for some answers but I am not finding anything I can use.

Thanks!

Comment: I doubt Microsoft is going to support SL. I had heard rumors of support being stopped after SL5, which now seem probable. I'd recommend HTML 5 for iOS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Silverlight as you know it does not work on iPad or other tablets, a version runs on Windows Phone 7 though. If you want to build a cross platform application, HTML 5 is the way to go.

Comment: Any idea on how Netflix does this? They use Silverlight for their watch instantly. It also works on iPhone, iPad, and some android devices. Are they using Silverlight?

Comment: The Android and iOS versions are platform specific applications that don't use Silverlight. Those versions don't run in-browser.